# Issue a get command from browser for a particular XML file

Tags: xml

To get this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <command action="retrieve" id="1234" code = "24" >
   </command>
</root>
```

I would always issue this GET command from the browser(using Tomcat server):

```
http://localhost:8080/program?command=retrieve&id=1234&code=24
```

But what if the XML changed, and now I have this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <command action="retrieve" id="1234" code = "24" >
      <subelement id = "1">SomeStringhere</subelement>
      <subelement id = "2">SomeOtherStringHere</subelement>
   </command>
</root>
```

How can I write my GET command now to integrate the subelements of the file ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapping of a URL onto a resource is dependent on the server.

How you get the server to respond to a request with the second set of example data depends on the servelet (or whatever) that you've written and mapped /program on to.